# Datables JS set cell value by row index and column index

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm doing an AJAX request which returns an Id.
The idea is to update my datatable without reloading the page.
I get the row index perfectly. And set the row class perfectly.
But now I want to set some values in some cells of that row.
And I can't get it. It says 'table.cell is not a function'.
Here's my code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "trasladosDespacharGuardar.php",
    success: function(result) {
        id = parseInt(result);
        var index = table.fnFindCellRowIndexes( id, 1 );
        var row = table.api().row(index).node();
        $(row).addClass('warning');

        //Up to this point , everything is perfect
        var cell = table.cell(index,5);
        cell.data('Helloo');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's been a while, but the variable `cell` is a reference to the DataTables API. Rather try `table.cell(index,5).data("Hello");` to set the cell's value.

Comment: i think that's the same thing that i'm doing. doesn't work.

Comment: @jason-aller if you're editing old posts be sure to correct all issues with the post, including tags and code formatting! Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use `cell` the way as suggested in OP, use the [**`{ row, column }`**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector) selector and finalize with `draw()` :

```js
table.cell({ row: index, column: 5 }).data('Helloo').draw();
```

---

Regarding *'table.cell is not a function'*, the dataTable is probably not initialized with `DataTable()`, capital `D`. If there is a reason for initializing with dataTable() we still have access to the API by `api()` :

```js
table.api().cell({ row: index, column: 5 }).data('Helloo').draw();
```

Comment: Right, I forgot for this case, the selector is an object. BTW, the statement, `the above answer is not correct`, presumably will itself no longer be correct when the OP comes back and accepts your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

though @davidkonrad 's answer is correct but there is one consideration - is that the rowIndex, is the order in which the row was loaded, not the order it is currently displayed.If you want it based on the current position in the table, it's probably easiest to use jQuery like this -

```
$('#yourTableId tbody tr:eq(rowIndex) td:eq(columnIndex)').text('yourvalue');
```